# Show that $\Pi X_n=X$ is totally bounded under $D$ (Munkres , page 280,Q.1)

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that each $X_n$ is metrizable with $d_n$, $D(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\sup\{\bar{d_i}(x_i,y_i) \}$ is a metric for the product space $X=\Pi X_n$. Show that $\Pi X_n=X$ is totally bounded under $D$.

My try:

Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$. There exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge n_0$ we have $n\epsilon \gt 1$.

Then $$B_{D}(\vec{x},\epsilon)=\{\vec{y}  | D(\vec{x},\vec{y}) \lt \epsilon\}=\{\vec{y}  | \sup\left(\frac{\bar{d_i}(x_i,y_i)}{i}\right) \lt \epsilon \forall i\}$$
$$=\{\vec{y}  | \bar{d}(x_i,y_i) \lt i \epsilon \forall i\}$$

Since forall $i \ge n_0$, $i \epsilon \gt 1$, we have $$B_{D}(\vec{x},\epsilon)=B_{d_1}(x_1,\epsilon)\times B_{d_2}(x_2,2\epsilon)\times..\times B_{d_{n_{0}-1}}(x_{n_{0}-1},(n_{0}-1)\epsilon)\times X_{n_0}\times X_{{n_0}+1}\times..$$

Now since each $X_i$ is totally bounded, $$X_i \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_i} B_{d_i}(y_{j}^{i},i\epsilon), i=1,2,...,n_0-1$$

Now let $$\bar{x_j}^i=(....,y_{j}^{i},...), j=1,2,..k_i, i=1,2,..n_0-1$$ ,where we replace $y_{j}^i$ in the $ith$ place and rest all we don't care.

Then $$ X \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_i} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_0-1} B_{D}(\bar{x}_j^i, \epsilon)$$

Is it alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

You’ve stated the problem incorrectly:

$$D(\vec x,\vec y)=\sup_i\frac{\bar d_i(x_i,y_i)}i\;,$$

and each $\langle X_n,d_n\rangle$ is totally bounded. Also, you should tell us that $\bar d_i(x,y)=\min\{d_i(x,y),1\}$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $x,y\in X_i$.

For the proof itself you have the right general idea, but you need to be more careful in defining the $\epsilon$-net at the end. For each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n_0-1\}$ you have a finite $F_i\subseteq X_i$ such that

$$X_i=\bigcup_{y\in F_i}B_{d_i}(y,i\epsilon)\;.$$

For $i\ge n_0$ let $y_i\in X_i$ be arbitrary, and let $F_i=\{y_i\}$. Finally, let $F=\prod_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}F_i$. Then $F$ is finite, and

$$X=\bigcup_{\vec x\in F}B_D(\vec x,\epsilon)\;.\tag{1}$$

The set that you used in place of my $F$ won’t necessarily work, so your conclusion that

> $$X \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k_i} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_0-1} B_{D}(\bar{x}_j^i, \epsilon)$$

isn’t necessarily true. To see why this is so, you should try to write out in some detail a proof of $(1)$, so that you see why you want $x_i\in F_i$ for each $\vec x\in F$ and $i\in\{1,\ldots,n_0-1\}$.